# Database connection and SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to connect to the database and echo information but it's don't work. Can someone help me with this? I connect to database in header.php file and try to use it in index.html where I use require_once header.php.

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$user = 'username';
$pass = '123';
$database = 'name';

$db_connection = new PDO( "mysql:host=" . $hostname . ";dbname=" . $database, $user, $pass );

$totalSpace = $db_connection->query( "SELECT SUM(file_server.totalSpaceUsed) FROM file_server" );
$totalRegisteredUsers = $db_connection->query( "SELECT COUNT(1) AS total FROM users WHERE status='active'" );
$totalDownloads = $db_connection->query( "SELECT SUM(visits) AS total FROM file" );
?>
```

When I trying to echo I don't get anything.

```
<h2 class="mb-0 mt-3 display-4 text-white"><span class="counter-value" data-count="50"><?php echo $totalRegisteredUsers; ?></span></h2>
```

Comment: "and try to use it in index.html" -- Are HTML files even interpreted by PHP on your server?

Comment: Also, you need to fetch/loop results. You can't just echo a result set.

Comment: '''<?php foreach ( $totalRegisteredUsers as $row ) { print_r($row); } ?>''' Now I've got Array ( [total] => 25543 [0] => 25543 ) but I want number

Comment: If the line `<h2 class="mb-0 mt-3 display-4 text-white"><span class="counter-value" data-count="50"><?php echo $totalRegisteredUsers; ?></span></h2>` is the result you get in your browser, then your webserver is not configured for running php from inside a html file. Try to rename the file to index.php or correct the configuration of your web server. Once you have done this, you will be able to debug your php code, as it contains errors.